# Prevent bootstrap popover closing based on a condition

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I have created a popover (bs-popover from [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers)) that automatically closes after clicking outside of popover. I want to stop closing popover when a condition is `true`.

I used this event listener:

```
$scope.$on('tooltip.hide.before', function(event, ui) {
    if(something === true){
        console.log('HERE');  // Writes HERE on close popover
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

But it fails to stop event. Any solution?

Comment: the first example doesn't close when clicked off http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers  - i've done something similar using angular-ui, but had to trap the click on the document, and prevent it being handler by bs

Comment: @sambomartin I want to auto close functionality be `active`. I want to conditionaly prevent it.

Comment: use $('body').on('click', function (e) {  /**/ } ); to prevent default and consume the event if you want to keep popover visible

Comment: @sambomartin Yes, Seems it's the only way. Thanks